# Closing a workbook from an other one without stopping code

Tags: vba, excel

**Issue :** I am encountering the issue that if I try to close a workbook from an other one, the code stops running.

This issue has been exposed in a few posts already but there doesn't seem to have a solution.

**What I am trying to do :**

1. I have a code in workbook WB1.xlsm called "Code1" which opens WB2 the following way `Workbooks.Open("WB2.xlsm").RunAutoMacros(xlAutoOpen)`
2. The Auto_Open code form WB2 is now running, I do my things in WB2 (copy data) and then the goal will be to paste those data in WB3 and close WB1 so I proceed as the following at the end of the Auto_Open code from WB2 before jumping into WB3:

   ```
   For Each wbk In Workbooks
     If wbk.Name = "WB1.xlsm" Then
       'wbk.Activate
       'DoEvents
       'ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        wbk.Close False
       'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "wbk.Close"
     End If
   Next
   Workbooks.Open(PathTo_WB3).RunAutoMacros (xlAutoOpen)
   ```

   The problem is that the code stops after closing WB1 ( above you can see different attempts to close it but they all fail...)

**Question :** Is it actually possible to close a workbook from an other one without seeing the code being stopped ?

Comment: You're closing the workbook that the code is running from if i'm not mistaken?

Comment: `If Not wbk Is ThisWorkbook Then wbk.Close False`

Comment: the code in the 2nd point is in the Auto_Open macro from WB2

Comment: Ah my bad sorry.

Comment: Which code is stopping? The `RunAutoMacros`? Your question needs to clarify that.

Comment: @Mat'sMug : tried it, same issue

Comment: I mean the whole code, it will reach the line `wbk.Close` , will close WB1 and then instead of going to `End If` the code just stops

Comment: Can you open WB3 before you close WB1?

Comment: You have *code* (A) that's running *code* (B), so when you say "the whole code", do you mean A or B? Is that code in WB1? `wbk.Close` is inside a loop that iterates all workbooks in the `ApplicationWorkbooks` collection, and that includes the workbook containing the code that's currently executing that loop (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`) - closing the file that contains the executing code will stop that code, that's just how it is. So please [edit] to clarify exactly what you mean, we're not looking at your screen and we can't read minds.

Comment: @D.O.  Sure I could, but I am just trying to fix this issue rather than trying to avoid it. I mean if there is no other way I could do this, but then the issue would come up later

Comment: @Mat'sMug I guess it is `WB1` calls `WB2` which tries to close `WB1`

Comment: Is that loop snippet in `WB1`? Why the hell would you alias `ThisWorkbook` with `WB1`

Comment: This is a normal behavior. Because the autorun of WB2 is within the context of the sub in WB1 which opened WB2. If you close WB1 within the autorun of WB2 you instantly kill that context which stops the run immediately. VBA can not multithread!

Comment: FWIW an `Auto_Open` macro that closes other workbooks is a very very bad idea.

Comment: You should reconsider your design. If I ever opened an Excel file and it closed everything else I was working on, I'd delete it and never use it again.   That's malware - not a macro.

Comment: @Peh : Yes that's what I feared...so basically there is no way to do this right ? Or could I somehow, from WB2, use a command which stops the code running in WB1 so that I can then close WB1 without issues ?

Comment: You have a conflated system.  Best to simplify.  You use wb1 to open wb2, and then you run macros in wb2, and then try to close wb1.  We don't know if the code to close wb1 is in wb1 or wb2.  Either way, you have too much code.  I'll guarantee it.  KISS - keep it simple, Silly.  Open all three wb's at the same time  and control all of them with one wb code.   You'll find debugging is much easier.  As well as updating when needed

Comment: @Seb you can do it with a button that a user clicks but not in any autorun or any automated way. Or just hide WB1 by minimizing and closing WB1 has to be the last thing autorun does, then it dosn't matter that the run gets killed ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I have a code in workbook WB1.xlsm called "Code1" which opens WB2*

So WB1 is the caller of WB2. Here's a golden rule:

#### He who opens a file, should be responsible for closing it.

That golden rule applies to many many many things in programming, and if you derive from it you're going to hit many many many problems.

- He who creates an object, should be responsible for destroying it.
- He who allocates a resource, should be responsible for deallocating it.
- ...

So you have a file named `WB1.xlsm` that contains code that's running - as far as execution context is concerned, that WB1 is `ThisWorkbook`.

So `ThisWorkbook` does this:

```
Workbooks.Open("WB2.xlsm").RunAutoMacros xlAutoOpen
```

That assumes the file opens successfully, and discards a precious object reference that you actually need... badly. Change it to this:

```
With Workbooks.Open("WB2.xlsm")
    .RunAutoMacros xlAutoOpen
    .Close False
End With
```

Now the automacros in `WB2` can do whatever they like, **except attempt to close WB1**.

So `WB2`'s automacro opens `WB3` - therefore `WB2` should also be responsible for closing `WB3`, because it's responsible for opening it - in `WB2.xlsm` you would have a `Workbook_BeforeClose` handler to make sure WB3 closes along with WB2. Or whatever - it's not clear at all why you would need an automacro to do this, or why WB1 can't just open WB2 and WB3.

Just keep your execution context / *call stack* in mind (the call originated from WB1, so until execution returns to WB1 you have stuff pending), and remember that VBA code lives inside a host document - if you close that document, the code ceases to exist.

Comment: Okeeeyyy ! Makes much more sense ! Can't believe I survived without knowing that rule until now ! Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: Note that the `With` block only captures the object reference (and correctly discards it on `End With`) - it *still* assumes that the file opens successfully.

Comment: Thanks for making my day :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior. Because the autorun of WB2 is within the context of the sub in WB1 which opened WB2. If you close WB1 within the autorun of WB2 you instantly kill that context which stops the run immediately.

A workaround could be hiding WB1 instead of closing (e.g. minimize it). And run close of WB1 as the very last action of autorun in WB2. This still aborts the autorun of WB2 but it doesn't matter because it was the last action.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you call the code in WB2 using the OnTime method. Suppose the routine in WB2 you want to start is called ContinueOpen:

```
Sub OpenWB2AndDoStuff()
    Workbooks.Open("WB2.xlsm")
    Application.Ontime Now, "'" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "'!ContinueOpen"
End Sub
```