# VBA - Execute Macro on Workbook Open

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 xlsm workbooks with a bunch of macros inside of them.. When each one is opened, the user is presented with a pop up that asks if they want to execute the Call_All macro which would run them all. If the user clicks yes, then it executes, and if no then nothing happens.

The reason I have done it this way, is because I am trying to automate the admin work as far as possible and make the process as "dummy proof" as I can for the users. So if I don't put the pop up to ask the user what they want to do and I simply call the Call_All macro in the "this workbook" file, then whenever the file is opened - even if it is to modify something (such as code), the entire macro will execute.

Now, the issue I am having is this:

I run a series of scripts and the very last script opens up the first workbook with the "Yes/No" pop up. When the user clicks on yes for this workbook, the macro's are executed perfectly. The very last macro in each workbook, opens up the next xlsm file, upon which the user is asked again if they want to execute the macros in the new workbook. However, this time it does not execute and absolutely nothing happens. The very same thing happens again when the next xlsm file is opened.

Note: If I open each xlsm file individually and click yes, then they work fine. It is only when I open the file from the previous workbook.

Here is the code to call the Call_All macro (This is in the "ThisWorkbook" File):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim varResponse As Variant

    varResponse = MsgBox("Run Macro?", vbYesNo, "Selection")
    If varResponse <> vbYes Then

        Exit Sub

    Else

        Call_All

    End If



End Sub
```

The code is exactly the same in all 3 workbooks.

Comment: Try to search in all your "macros" for these line - `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Is it present?

Comment: @Vityata There isn't any line with 'Application.EnableEvents = False' but there is 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' & 'Application.DisplayAlerts = False'

Comment: are they followed by `'Application.ScreenUpdating = True' & 'Application.DisplayAlerts = True'` ? because if no then you are turning screen updating off and never turning it back on, hence nothing appears to happen when you run the macro because the screen is not updating

Comment: @Banana I put the 'Application.ScreenUpdating = True' & 'Application.DisplayAlerts = True' at the end of the macro before the next workbook is opened and it still has not changed anything..

Comment: @Banana I have even put Application.EnableEvents = True in the "ThisWorkbook" file of the workbook that is opened

Comment: I stumbled on this line:  _make the process as "dummy proof" as I can_ .... never underestimate a sufficiently talented dummy they will **** your spreadsheet up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @Rory in a separate post. I continued to receive the same issue even with @Jerry's answer above.

This was the reason:

*Closing the first workbook that called the code in the second one.*

@Rory said:

*Then I suspect that is your issue - that code is the caller of the code you're currently running. If you end that, you end the called code too. I suggest you try using Application.OnTime to call the code in the second workbook so that the first code can actually finish before the workbook is closed.*

This I could not unfortunately get @Rory's suggestion for Application.OnTime to work either, however, I found the below link which explains why:

[Closing a workbook from an other one without stopping code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790856/closing-a-workbook-from-an-other-one-without-stopping-code/42791666#42791666)

Answer (score 0):

.
Look at this resource (about half way down the page:
https://exceloffthegrid.com/how-to-run-a-macro-from-another-workbook/

```
Sub CallAnotherMacro()

Application.Run "'Another Workbook.xlsm'!NameOfMacro"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was doing the same thing but I figured out why. I have posted the answer below.

Comment: My post was "below" yours but when marked as the answer it was moved to under my original question. Please refer above.